# Cycling through attack modifiers in Dota 2

Tags: dota-2

I understand that attack modifiers do not stack with each other. And I also want to know how multiple picking up more than one attack modifier changes behaviour in Dota 2.

In HoN, you can cycle through each modifier by assigning a single shortcut key. Is it possible to do the same in Dota 2? If so, please explain to me how it is done.

Comment: Just as an aside, it's rare that you would want to have multiple UAM items as there tend to be better items with other benefits.

Comment: Indeed. You really shouldn't bother stacking orb effects unless you happen to be just that farmed. If you build an item with one of these effects, you get considerably diminishing returns from buying an item with another UAM over an item that doesn't have one.

Comment: @Dispensador Not really. Deso lasts for 15 seconds, for example. No reason you can't grab something on top of that and cycle, if it's easy enough to execute.

Comment: @franglais Most MM games that I play lasts up to 50+ minutes, some even go to the extent of base race. So having an option where I can cycle through UAM will make the game more interesting as I can go 1v5 against enemy team.

Comment: @Decency I wish to cycle Desolator and Dominator, one hit with Desolator and then switch to Dominator and continue attacking. I am sure it will work well if I can toggle UAM on the fly.

Comment: As T_O answered you would need to drop the UAMs you don't want and then pick them up again. Some items that change your attacks will stack with others (auras are different from UAM, so having Vladmir's Offering and Desolator will work together).

At the same time, Maelstrom or Mjollnir will partially work with UAMs, since they only remove the UAM effect when the lightning strikes. Additionally, the Eye of Skadi stacks with alot of UAMs (not just on ranged heros as it was stated during the early days of dota2).

Comment: @Rai in this case, just purchase Vladmir's Offering instead of the Helm of the Dominator and you're golden. This way you have both lifesteal and the -armor on hit, but you can't upgrade the HotD to Satanic later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Unique_Attack_Modifier#Priority

Regarding items specifically, the oldest has the priority, so if you want to "toggle" Unique Attack Modifiers, you have to drop all your UAM items and pick first the one that has the UAM you want to use.

Comment: IF you have 2 i think you can drop the one you dont want and pick it up again (instead of droping all) but I'm not 100% sure. I also remember something about items order in the inventory deciding for Orb effect priority but I might just have made that up. Ill check in game quickly when i have time

Comment: I think the slot priority is for illusions (regarding phantom lancer skadi + diffusal) but its sure as hell not on the wiki. I think it's the same concept though, as illusions must have a way to determine if an item is older than another when they spawn with several items at the same time. Inventory slot must do the trick. I don't know which is the correct order

Comment: @wizliz also yes you don't need to drop every single UAM item you just have to keep the only one you want to get the UAM from and drop/pick the other ones

Comment: @WizLiz Dropping and picking up UAM items in middle of a team fight is not really feasible, right?

Comment: @T_O Illusions can just copy the same inventory info from the original hero at the time of creation right? Why would you want another set of tracking just to create an illusion? And I don't think it is feasible to drop and pick up UAM items in middle of a team fight or when you are chasing an enemy with low health.